# Does forward_list supported on xlc

Tags: stl, aix, xlc, forward-list

I am porting my code to xlC.
Wondering if forward_list is supported by xlC?
i tried with test program

```
#include <forward_list>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::forward_list<int> fl;
    std::cout<<"Hello";
    return 0;
}
```

Its compiling fine on g++ but giving errror on xlC.
tried following compile line:
xlC forward_list_test.cpp
xlC -D __IBMCPP_TR1__ forward_list_test.cpp
But error is same:
"forward_list_test.cpp", line 1.10: 1540-0836 (S) The #include file  is not found.

if its supported do we need to add something extra to compile it?
Note: using xlC 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forward_list is new with the C++2011 standard, and is not currently supported by XL C/C++ for AIX.

Dwayne Moore
IBM Compilers Product Management and Design